# Class with two fields with same SerializedName

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I have a problem with my services because the same field is different form in request and response, whereby I use `@Expose` annotation to serialize one and deserialize another:

```
@SerializedName("photo")
@Expose(deserialize = false)
private String imageB64;

@SerializedName("photo")
@Expose(serialize = false)
private ImageURL imageURL;
```

But in the response, my service is launching an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class User declares multiple JSON fields named photo
```

I'm using Retrofit with GSON converter.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to add multiple `@SerializedName` annotations, because otherwise you'll get the error you provided.

However, you can create a custom `TypeAdapter` to manually hand serialization/deserialization of your object, like that:

#### MyObject

```
public class MyObject {

  private String url;

  private int number;

  // constructor + getters + setters + custom "toString()"
  ...

}
```

#### MyObjectTypeAdapter

```
class MyObjectTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<MyObject> {

  @Override
  public void write(JsonWriter out, MyObject value) throws IOException {
    out.beginObject().name("photo").value(value.getUrl()).endObject();
  }

  @Override
  public MyObject read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    MyObject result = new MyObject();
    in.beginObject();
    while (in.hasNext()) {
      switch (in.nextName()) {
      case "photo":
        result.setNumber(in.nextInt());
      }
      // other fields
      ...
    }

    in.endObject();
    return result;
  }
}
```

You can use it in this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(MyObject.class, new MyObjectTypeAdapter()).create();

  System.out.println(gson.toJson(new MyObject("myUrl", 1)));

  MyObject deserialized = gson.fromJson("{ \"photo\": 12 }", MyObject.class);

  System.out.println(deserialized);
}
```

and it prints (note I used a custom `toString()` for `MyObject`):

```
{"photo":"myUrl"}
MyObject{url='null', number=12}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've found a solution through this answer, making a TypeAdapterFactory instead TypeAdapter and using this https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.7/com/google/gson/Gson.html#getDelegateAdapter-com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory-com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken- because I have several objects with the same structure and the solution must be one for all.

Answer (score 0):

```
@SerializedName("photo")
private Object imageUrl;


public String getImageB64()
{
    return (String) this.imageUrl
}

public void setImageB64( String image )
{
    this.imageUrl = image
}

public ImageURL getimageURL()
{
    return (ImageURL) this.imageUrl
}

public void setimageURL( ImageURL imageUrl )
{
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).